# bash: /drives/c/Users/admin/DOCUME~1/MobaXterm/slash/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

Tags: cygwin, mobaxterm

I placed CygUtils.plugin into Mobaxterm directory, but, when I try linux command in local terminal of Mobaxterm, it shows below error.
Coud anyone help this?

[bob.MGKRD35-NA1081A] ➤ ls -al
bash: /drives/c/Users/admin/DOCUME~1/MobaXterm/slash/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLVXk.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue. This is what I did :

Backed up the session into a file, ( Export All sessions to a file)

Uninstalled the MobaXtreme

Removed filed under DOCUME~1/MobaXterm/

Re-installed and imported sessions. It worked

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked!!